# Bing web search API reply limit?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I signed up for the cognitive services Bing web search API- the free version. My replies  always are limited to 50. The documentation doesn't mention a limit in replies. Does anyone know if this is a limit of the free version (I have tried using offset to see if I just needed to do a second call but offset doesn't seem to affect my results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John here from the Bing API team. The results are capped to 50 as you said. We will update the documentation soon, thanks for catching this.

To get additional results, you need to use a combination of the `&count` and `&offset` parameters as described in this article: [How to page through results from the Bing Web Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/paging-webpages).